# Compute number of files changed between 2 labels

Tags: perforce

Is there a better way than below method to compute number of files changed between 2 labels?

```
p4 files @P4LABEL1 > /tmp/1
p4 files @P4LABEL2 > /tmp/2
sort /tmp/1 > /tmp/1s
sort /tmp/2 > /tmp/2s
diff /tmp/1s /tmp/2s | grep '^>' | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p4 diff2 -q //...@P4LABEL1 //...@P4LABEL2